# Yii2 pass query result to a action in another controller

Tags: yii2, audit

I'm trying to insert record into my audit table upon update of record in any other table. For example, if a user update his profile I want to store the old record and the newly updated record in my audit table. For this in my user model I'm trying to use beforeSave() and pass the value to my audit controller

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if((parent::beforeSave($insert))){
                        // Place your custom code here
                        $query = DepCustomer::findOne($this->customer_id);
                        Yii::$app->runAction('audit-trial/createaudit', ['query' => $query]);
                return true;
        }
    }
```

And the action code in audit controller for now

```
public function actionCreateaudit($query)
{
    $model = new Audit();

            $model->old = '';
            foreach($query as $name => $value){
                //$temp = $name .': '. $value.',  ';
                //$contentBefore[] = $temp;
                $audit->old = $audit->old.$name .': '. $value. ', ';
            } 
            // I've not yet any other code for now I'm trying to get the old value
            $model->save();
}
```

I'm getting 404 not found error. What do I need to change in my code to make it work? Thank you!

Comment: do you have any special logic in the action "createaudit", if you dont why not saving the query in the beforesave method . if you have a special logic it's better to move it to the model "AuditTrial" and then you can call it from any where in your code

Comment: Yeah! its true. I can save the old and new updated data in the beforesave method or in the update action of the customer controller and I have achived this. Now I'm trying to save the audit record of other model also. So I'm trying to write the code to pass the old value in beforesave method, so that i can put the code in other model also.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `runAction()` . If you want to perform operation on another model, prefer to create a static function in that model (in your case `Audit` model) to save the data

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if((parent::beforeSave($insert))){
                        // Place your custom code here
                        $query = DepCustomer::findOne($this->customer_id);
                       Audit::saveOldDetails($query);
                return true;
        }
    }
```

and write `saveOldDetails` function in `Audit Model`

```
public static saveOldDetails($query){
 // your business logic here
}
```

Refer this link
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#runAction()-detail

Comment: Hi! with this method the same record are getting inserted into audit table multiple times. Like 3 times. I've been trying to figure out what is causing this but couldn't find the reason. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: `beforeSave` will get executed for each save method.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. My update action has multiple save() in it.